# R - How to sum all values based on both a certain date AND string?

Tags: r, tidyverse

I'm currently working with a data frame where I wish to summarize drug dosage per day per patient. With the tidyverse I tried using a

```
df%>%
group_by (patient, date)%>%
summarise(doseperday = aggregate(drugdose)
```

but no luck.

I.e.

```
|patient|drugdose|date    |
|Bob    |5       |10/10/18|
|Bob    |3       |10/10/18|
|Bob    |4       |10/11/18|
|Bob    |1       |10/11/18|
|Jim    |5       |10/10/18|
|Jim    |8       |10/10/18|
|Jim    |3       |10/11/18|
|Jim    |1       |10/11/18|
```

I want to get the following:

```
|patient|drugdose|date    |
|Bob    |8       |10/10/18|
|Bob    |5       |10/11/18|
|Jim    |12      |10/10/18|
|Jim    |4       |10/11/18|
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Use `sum` instead of `aggregate`, plus you are missing one parenthesis

Comment: Adding to the client above, make sure to use `ungroup()` afterward.

Comment: Dplyr solution
df2 <-
df%>%
group_by (patient, date)%>%
summarise(doseperday = sum(drugdose)) %>%
ungroup()

df2

Base R solution

df2 <- aggregate(drugdose~patient+date, df, sum)